# Cannot get c# to send email from hotmail

Tags: c#, email, smtp, hotmail

When I run this code, I get an error :

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> 
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server 
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 65.55.163.152:587

Code :

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    string smtpAddress = "smtp.live.com";
    int portNumber = 587;
    bool enableSSL = true;
    string emailFrom = "xxxxx@hotmail.co.uk";
    string password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    string emailTo = "myname@businessemail.co.uk";
    string subject = "Daily Email Check";
    string body = "Email reached business exchange server from an external hotmail email account";

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
        mail.To.Add(emailTo);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

        try 
        {
            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error\n\n {0}", e);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure there are no firewalls between you and smtp.live.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
 using System.Net.Mail;

...

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("xxxxx@hotmail.co.uk", "myname@businessemail.co.uk");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "smtp.live.com";
mail.Subject = "Daily Email Check";
mail.Body = "Email reached business exchange server from an external hotmail email account";
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I found a solution. It appears that Hotmail doesn't support STMP.            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailaddressReceptor);
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Subject = messageSubjectTxt;
            message.Body = "Show me the email";
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(emailserver);
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@hotmail.co.uk", "xxxxxxx");
            client.Send(message);